# How to randomise database field reads? [ReactJS & Firestore]

Tags: reactjs, google-cloud-firestore

I am currently working on a quiz-like application in React and using Firestore to store my questions and multiple choice answers. Currently, I have my answers and wrong answers in the following fields: answer, wrongAnswer1, wrongAnswer2 and wrrongAnswer3. I know this probably isn't the best way to do it, I am not very experienced in backend.

Currently I am rendering in the answer and wrongAnswer fields, however, they are obviously rendering in the same position for every question, what would be the best way to render these so they are random?

I am imagining that I would have to put them into an array of some sort, but I'm not sure how I would do this.

Any help would be very much appreciated!

Cheers,
Ryan

EDIT:

Current code for my multiple choice questions:

```
   render() {
        return (
            <div className = "MultipleChoice">
                <h1> Multiple Choice </h1>
                <form>
                <label> {this.props.question}  </label>
                <input type = "radio" name = {this.props.question} /> {this.props.answer}
                <input type = "radio" name = {this.props.question} /> {this.props.wrongAnswer}
                <input type = "radio" name = {this.props.question} /> {this.props.wrongAnswer2}
                <input type = "radio" name = {this.props.question} /> {this.props.wrongAnswer3}
                </form>
            </div>
        )
    }
```

Props are passed in through app.js

```
<MultipleChoice  question = {questionType.question} answer = {questionType.answer} wrongAnswer = {questionType.wrongAnswer} wrongAnswer2 = {questionType.wrongAnswer2} wrongAnswer3 = {questionType.wrongAnswer3}/>
```

Database structure:
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since no code or data structures is given, it's hard to write solution which will suit best in your particular case.
If you already is using any utility library, you can search for needed tool in this library. For example `lodash` has [shuffle method](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#shuffle) which is doing exactly what you need.
That said, you don't need to add `lodash` only for one method. `Math.random()` can do smth similar.

```
const unshuffledAnswers = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];
const shuffledAnswers = [];

const pick = (collection) => {
   var card = Math.floor(Math.random() * collection.length);
   return collection.splice(card, 1)[0];
}

for (let i = 0, length = unshuffledAnswers.length; i < length; i++) {
  shuffledAnswers.push(pick(unshuffledAnswers));
}
```

**UPDATED**
Code of component with answers can look like (if your component is class component, not functional one)

```js
pick = (collection) => {
   var card = Math.floor(Math.random() * collection.length);
   return collection.splice(card, 1)[0];
}

get answers() {
  const { question, answer, wrongAnswer, wrongAnswer2, wrongAnswer3 } = this.props;
  const unshuffledAnswers = [answer, wrongAnswer, wrongAnswer2, wrongAnswer3];
  const shuffledAnswers = [];

  for (let i = 0, length = unshuffledAnswers.length; i < length; i++) {
    shuffledAnswers.push(pick(unshuffledAnswers));
  }

  return shuffledAnswers.map(answer => <input type = "radio" name =  
    {this.props.question} value={answer}/> );
}

render() {
  return (
    <div className = "MultipleChoice">
      <h1> Multiple Choice </h1>
      <form>
        <label> {this.props.question}  </label>
        {this.answers}
      </form>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this, I'll add in my data structure and code now!

Comment: Feel free to mark answer as right one if it'll work for you :)

Comment: @RyanNisbet I've updated a solution based on your update